# How to add data from a model type list into an array

Tags: java

I am trying to add items from my model list onto a spinner. The syntax for adding it onto the spinner requires an Array Adapter which contains the array of the items wished to be added. I have created an array of the size of my model list but I do not understand how to put elements from my model list into my array. Below is my code:

```
String items[] = new String[models_list.size()];
    final ViewHolder myViewHolder = (ViewHolder)viewHolder;
    final Department_model model = models_list.get(i);
    myViewHolder.text.setText("Department");
    myViewHolder.spinner_text.setText(items[i]);

spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.department_list, items);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.department_list);
    myViewHolder.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

When I am initializing my array Adpater, the 'items' array is empty.
Help would be highly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: can you print `items.length` and check the value? if `models_list.size()` is 0 then, the array will be `empty`. 
I do not see where `i` is being defined.

Comment: I have figured it out. I have made a loop until items' length and have put the items from the list at the jth position of the loop. Below is my code:
    for(int j=0; j<items.length; j++){
            items[j] = models_list.get(j).getCategory_Name();
            spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.category_list, items);
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.category_list);
            myViewHolder.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        }

Comment: Please add your code in your question. it will be easy to understand